# Getting the top 5 used words from a chunk of text in java

Tags: java, dictionary, text

I'm trying to get the top 5 used words from a chunk of text. I have built up a map of words which includes a value of how many times the word has been used.

```
Map<String,Integer> wordHits = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for(Status status3 : statuses){

    String mdry = status3.getText();
    String[] statusSplitOnSpace = mdry.split(" ");

    for(String wordInStatus : statusSplitOnSpace){
        for(String str : statusSplitOnSpace){
                if(doesListContainWord(str)){
                incrementKeyofWordInList(str);
            }else{
                if(doesWordCountAsAWord(str)){
                    addNewWordToList(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Set keys = list.keySet();
for (Iterator i = keys.iterator(); i.hasNext() ;){
      String key = (String) i.next();
      String value = (String) list.get(key);
      //if(value.length()>10)
      System.out.println("Word (" + key + ") was found " + value + " times.");
      //else{
}
```

Comment: `list.keySet()` - a list doesn't have a keySet. A map does. Are you confusing yourself ? :)

Comment: Sorry i did not get your idea

Comment: Alfasin is right. Class "List" or "ArrayList" does not have a keySet() member.  Is your object named "list" a "Map"?  Maps have keys and values.  Arrays, Lists, ArrayLists do not.

Comment: my object named list

Comment: @sara what is the `type` of the variable you call `list` ? Where did you declare it and how ?

Comment: Yes.  Your objected named "list".  What is it's type?  What are the lines of code are missing where the object is declared / instantiated? Assuming this is a map, key contains a word and value contains a count?  Why is value a String?  Why is it not an int or Integer?

Comment: this line you mean?  static Map<String,String> list = new HashMap<String , String>();

Comment: That's it! You should not call that object "list".  A "list" is not a "map". That is confusing.

Comment: Look to my "answer" to help move this conversation along...

Comment: gonzo's answer is a really good one, but I'm afraid it may be too advanced for that stage you are in with your Java knowledge.  Let's find a more novice level approach.

Comment: I edited my post please have a look at it once again. I'm sorry

Comment: I guess your object named "list" is supposed to be "wordHits" ?  I called it "wordCountMap" in my solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more novice level "manual" approach.  I didn't test it, but it's got to be close...

```
        // Get sorted Lists of words and counts from the source Map
    List<String> sortedWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Integer> sortedCountsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();              
    for( String word : wordCountMap.keySet() ) 
    {
        Integer wordCount = wordCountMap.get(word);

        int insertIndex=0;
        for( int i=0; i != sortedCountsList.size(); ++i )
        {
            if( wordCount > sortedCountsList.get(i) ) break;
            ++insertIndex;  
        }     
        sortedWordsList.add( insertIndex, word );
        sortedCountsList.add( insertIndex, wordCount );
    }

    // Move top 5 words into a new List
    final int TOP_WORDS_TO_FIND_COUNT = 5;        
    List<String> topWordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for( int i=0; i != sortedWordsList.size(); ++i )
    {
        topWordsList.add( i, sortedWordsList.get(i) );
        if( i == TOP_WORDS_TO_FIND_COUNT-1 ) break;
    }     

    // Move top 5 counts into a new List
    List<Integer> topCountsList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for( int i=0; i != sortedCountsList.size(); ++i )
    {
        topCountsList.add( i, sortedCountsList.get(i) );
        if( i == TOP_WORDS_TO_FIND_COUNT-1 ) break;
    }
```

Comment: but i need to display both the word and its count

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but i already have the list of words and the count of iterations. i only need the function of top 5 used words based on my variable(keys) of words, and the variable(value) of the count.

Comment: Now "topWordsList" and "topCountsList" contain the top 5 of each, just broken into 2 Lists.  Their indexes directly correlate though. So topWordsList.get(0) has its count in topCountsList(0), and topWordsList.get(1) has its count in topCountsList(1), etc. Further it's all sorted...

Comment: Your "list", i.e. map was not sorted in any manner.  I sorted it into 2 pieces by the counts.  Then, I just created subsets, i.e. smaller lists from the full size ones.  You have a lot more now to work with, including your goal of 5.  When you want to change the total to say the top 10 words, just change the value of TOP_WORDS_TO_FIND_COUNT.

Comment: Cool. You're welcome.  Thanks for the upvote and accepted answer!  Considering I didn't test it, I'm especially glad it worked!

Comment: Sorry but i get this error: method get(iterator) is undefined for the type string

Comment: I changed your Iterator named "i" to "it", and then I created some ints named i.  Did that perhaps create a mismatch for you somewhere?  What line is the error referring to?  Else, maybe I have the iterator syntax wrong - I based it off your initial code and didn't double check that.  Unfortunately, I'm clocking out for the day...

Comment: Ok.  Last edit possible for the day.  Check out the revision.  That's another way to iterate through a Map.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your words stored in an array, first I would transfer the words to a `Map`. I believe you were trying to do that but it is hard to tell with your variable names. After you do this, you can create a custom `Comparator` that you can utilize to sort your `Map`. You can do something like this:

```
 public class Solution {           
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] words = {"word1", "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word5", "word5"};
        Map<String, Integer> wordCounts = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : words){ //Transfer your words to a map
            if (wordCounts.containsKey(word)){ //If word is already in map, increase value
                wordCounts.put(word, wordCounts.get(word)+1);
            }else{ //If word is not in map, add it to the map
                wordCounts.put(word, 1);
            }
        }
        TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedWordCounts = new TreeMap<>(new ValueComparator(wordCounts));  //Sorts based off of counts
        sortedWordCounts.putAll(wordCounts); //Add to new map
        NavigableSet<String> keys = sortedWordCounts.descendingKeySet();
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.println(keys.pollLast());  //This prints out the top 5 keys. 
        }
    }
}
class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    private Map<String,Integer> map;
    public ValueComparator(Map<String,Integer> map){
        this.map = map;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (map.get(o1)>=map.get(o2)){
            return -1;
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Output

```
word5
word1
word4
word3
word2
```

A `TreeMap` is a type of `Map` but sorts the map for you depending on the `Comparator` you initialize it with. If you do not give it a `Comparator` it will just sort by the keys and we do not want that. We want to sort by the values, so you have to write your own `Comparator`.

Comment: Upvote for the better answer in an "absolute sense".  Can I get one back for my "relative skill level" answer?